# Realizando GroupBy com Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Estou tentando realizar um GroupBy mas não estou conseguindo. Sempre retorna uma Exception que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Como faço para resolver esse problema ?

**LINQ**

```
public ActionResult MeusConcursos(){
            Usuario _usuario = Session["Usuario"] as Usuario;   

            //agrupa concurso         
            var query = context.numerosSorteio.GroupBy(n => n.concurso.id).OrderBy(n => n.Key); 
            //casting para lista
            IList<NumeroSorteio> numeros = (List<NumeroSorteio>)query;
            //define valores para o model
            IList<MeusConcursosModel> _lista = numeros.Where(x => x.usuario.id == _usuario.id)
                                                                       .Select(x => new MeusConcursosModel
                                                                       {
                                                                           id = x.concurso.id,
                                                                           dataRealizado = x.concurso.dataFinalizado,
                                                                           premio = x.concurso.premio.nome,
                                                                           valorUnit = x.valor,
                                                                           statusDesc = x.concurso.status
                                                                       })
                                                                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
                                                                       .ToList();


            return View(_lista);
        }
```

**Exception**

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PremiosOn.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int64,NumeroSorteio]]' no tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NumeroSorteio]'.
```

Comment: ao que parece o resultado do seu group é um `Int64`e não uma `List<NumeroSorteio>`

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que isso deve resolver o problema:

```
IList<MeusConcursosModel> _lista = numeros.Where(x => x.usuario.id == _usuario.id).Select(x =>
new MeusConcursosModel
{
    id = x.concurso.id,
    dataRealizado = x.concurso.dataFinalizado,
    premio = x.concurso.premio.nome,
    valorUnit = x.valor,
    statusDesc = x.concurso.status
})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.id)
    .SelectMany(r => r)
    .ToList();
```

O `SelectMany()` retorna um `IEnumareble` genérico onde se da para converter para o modelo.